# ElasticSearch [field_sort] unknown field [format]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I'm adding a `sort` conditions field to my ElasticSearch query. I'm using **ES 7.14 / Kibana 7.10**.
My `sort` array field look like

```
[
                    
    { "update_date": { "order": "desc", "missing" : "_last", "unmapped_type" : "long", "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos" } },
    { "release_date": { "order": "desc", "missing" : "_last", "unmapped_type" : "long", "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos" } }
]
```

where I have used: `desc` ordering, `_last` for `missing` values; `long` for `unmapped_type`, and `strict_date_optional_time_nanos` for `format`.
The query builder complains that

```
node:15873) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [x_content_parse_exception] [1:275] [field_sort] unknown field [format]
```

despite of the `format` field [is available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) in ES 7.14. If I remove the `format` field, it works, but I have no control over the sorting fields I'm using. So how to specify the sorting fields format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `format` parameter was [released](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/release-notes-7.13.0.html) in [7.13](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/69192) so your Kibana 7.10 doesn't know about it and hence complains when sending the query.

You should always keep [your component versions in synch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/7.14/upgrading-elastic-stack.html) when upgrading to prevent incompatibilities such as the one you describe from happening.

So the solution is simple: **upgrade Kibana to 7.14.**

Comment: so even if I'm using `ES 7.14`?

Comment: The error comes from Kibana, that's the weakest link

Comment: ok it makes sense. Thanks, last question, just realized, possibly unrelated to this error: why the score value is `null` when applying the `sort` clausole? Is that ok?

Comment: the score depends on your query, not the sorting. don't hesitate to create another question related to that different issue

Comment: Posted it separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68861970/elasticseach-score-field-is-null-when-sorting