# ElasticSeach score field is null when sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have added a `sort` conditions field to my ElasticSearch query. I'm using **ES 7.14 / Kibana 7.10**, with a "fallback" to the document's score. According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) I have to use the reserved key `_score`:

My `sort` array field look like

```
[
                    
    { "update_date": { "order": "desc", "missing" : "_last", "unmapped_type" : "long" } },
    { "release_date": { "order": "desc", "missing" : "_last", "unmapped_type" : "long" } },
    "_score"
]
```

This works ok, but I get a `null` value for `score` when not using the `_score` special field. Why? Is the `score` not calculated when using the `sort` conditions at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct that sort will not calculate when sorting applied
to another field. ES Documentation is quoted below for same:

> When sorting on a field, scores are not computed. By setting track_scores to true, scores will still be computed and tracked.

So If you want to calculate score then you can enable by providing "track_scores": true  parameter.

```
{
  "track_scores": true,
  "sort" : [
    { "post_date" : {"order" : "desc"} },
    { "name" : "desc" },
    { "age" : "desc" }
  ],
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So setting `track_scores=true` is alternative to using `_score` in the `sort` field or the score will be calculated differently in those two cases?

Comment: _score will be calculated same in both the scenario just difference is that, it will not applied sort on _score field, so when you add _score in sort then it will calculate score as well as it will apply sorting.

Comment: @loretoparisi Just want to share that, Score is only required when you want to search data based on relevancy, if you not need a score while applying sorting on another field then it is good practice to ignore it. Because score calculation with the sorting is a costly operation and it will impact performance as well.